# javaScript how to execute method by condition?

Tags: javascript, events, handler

I have to execute javascript method when the global variable is reached to some value, for example if x=10 then do doSomething(); Variable can be increased from multiple locations after each successful asynchronous request.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as the question you asked less than an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690675/how-to-handle-event-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: @JamesAllardice Yes, but that was closed.

Comment: @JuanMendes - It would have been better to edit the original question and get it to a state where it could be reopened rather than creating a new one. Now it's irrelevant since the original question has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

A solution without any timer or polling:

```
var X = {    // global variable
    value: 0,
    set: function(v) {
             X.value = v;
             if (X.value == 10) { 
                 // do what you like, e.g.
                 alert("X == 10"); 
             }
          }
 };

 X.set(3);
 X.set(X.value + 7);  // "do what you like" gets executed
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not offer native data binding features, you have to rely on polling:

```
globalVar = 0;

setInterval(function(){

if (globalVar >= 10) {
  globarVarChangeHandler();
}

}, 100);
```

In the code above I defined a function which will be executed each 100 milliseconds and if the globalVar has reached a minimum value of 10 an hypothetical globarVarChangeHandler() will be called.

Comment: Yuck, polling for variable changes? Please don't use this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a global variable why dont you use a `input` text field (with `display:none`) and update this field's value. Thean you can apply `onchange` event on this field to trigger your `doSomething()` method

Comment: Would work, but there's no need for a DOM element, that's overkill